# Which jar to use for Dynamodb with java

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm trying to write a DAO for DynamoDB using Java 8 and there seems to be several ways. Classes are primarily defined under the following two packages:

- `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2`
- `software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb`

Both of them appear to be doing what I'd like - but since I'm starting fresh, I'd rather choose the latest one

I've looked at these two links:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Java.03.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/migration-guide/whats-different.html

The thing that confuses the most is that the `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB` says v2 and `software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbClient` doesn't.

Comment: Posting a comment as I am not intimately familiar with the AWS SDK. It looks like `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2` is a package within the SDK the `v2` references the Dynamo version while the SDK version can be either 1.x or 2.x. So the 1.0 SDK can call Dynamo 2.0 and the 2.0 SDK can also call Dynamo 2.0. The safe path would typically be to follow the download links (or use a dependency manager!) from Amazon https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/ . This download page also shows github links that can help you review the code or package names.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [aws-sdk-java-v2](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2) repository uses the package name `software.amazon.awssdk` whereas [v1 of the Java SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java) uses `com.amazonaws`. v2 was written with Java 1.8 features in mind, making it a lot easier to develop with over v1.

I personally recommend using v2 over v1 where possible, even though both SDKs are still actively maintained on GitHub. However, there may be features that are missing from v2 that are contained in v1, so it's possible that you'll end up adding both as dependencies to your project.

To answer your question, `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2` is a package in v1 of the Java SDK, as seen [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/package-summary.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appears like the following: 
compile group: 'software.amazon.awssdk', name: 'dynamodb', version: '2.7.20'

Comment: Yes, that dependency is correct. Keep an eye on the `.changes` directory in the `aws-sdk-java-v2` repository for updates (the dependency patch version tends to update every day).