# Fetch table size from dynamodb using scala

Tags: scala, amazon-dynamodb

Hi I am using the following code to fetch various things from DynamoDB using Scala.
I am stuck at fetching the table description.

I get the following error when I build my project:

*constructor DescribeTableRequest in class DescribeTableRequest cannot be accessed in class dynDBMetadata
val tableDescription = ddbClient.describeTable(new DescribeTableRequest("Music"))*

```
package dynDBFetchAPIs

import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.{AwsBasicCredentials, StaticCredentialsProvider}
import software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbClient
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.DescribeTableRequest

class dynDBMetadata {

  def dynDBMetadataInit(): Unit = {
    regionDetails()
  }

  def regionDetails(): Unit = {
    val ddbClient = getDynDBClient()
    val region = Region.US_EAST_1
    var tableCount: Int = 0
    var tableSize: Map[String, Int] = null
    var regionSize: Int = 0

    val tableList = ddbClient.listTables().tableNames()

    val tableIterator = tableList.iterator()
    while (tableIterator.hasNext) {
      tableCount = tableCount + 1
      tableIterator.next()
    }

    val descTabReq = new DescribeTableRequest("Music")
    val tableDescription = ddbClient.describeTable(descTabReq)
    println(tableDescription)

    println("Region of AWS DynamoDB: " + region)
    println("List of DynamoDB Tables: " + tableList)
    println("Count of DynamoDB Tables: " + tableCount)
  }

  private def getDynDBClient(): DynamoDbClient = {
    var awsBasicCredentials: AwsBasicCredentials = null
    var dynamoDbClient: DynamoDbClient = null
    try {
      val accessKey = "****************************"
      val secretKey = "****************************"
      awsBasicCredentials = AwsBasicCredentials.create(accessKey, secretKey)

      dynamoDbClient = DynamoDbClient.builder()
        .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
        .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsBasicCredentials))
        .httpClient(ApacheHttpClient.builder().build())
        .build();

    } catch {
      case e: Exception => {
        e.printStackTrace()
      }
    }
    dynamoDbClient
  }

}
```

**Why is the given constructor not accessible when I use Scala?**

contents of build.sbt

```
name := "dynamodb"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
scalacOptions := Seq("-target:jvm-1.8")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "software.amazon.awssdk" % "dynamodb" % "2.15.1"
)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57433717/which-jar-to-use-for-dynamodb-with-java

Answer (score 1):

I believe that happends because class software.amazon.awssdk.services.**dynamodb**.model.DescribeTableRequest doesn't have a primary constructor.

You should create with the builder, like this

```
 val tableRequest = DescribeTableRequest.builder
            .tableName(tableName)
            .build
```

com.amazonaws.services.**dynamodbv2**.model.DescribeTableRequest instead, does have a primary constructor. So, maybe you've just included a wrong dependency.